# CSV file doesnot downloaded from server in php

Tags: php, excel

I am new to php and have php code which download record from server.
It works fine on my local server but does not work at server side.
at server side it redirect me to controller but in local in works fine.
To download the csv file i have created a new controller file.
here is my code

through this javascript code I am calling my controller

```
function exportcustomer()
   {
    window.location=site_url+'controllers/ajax_controller/user-export-controller.php';
}`
```

and here are the headers

```
$filename =  "UserReport.csv";
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
    header('Pragma: public');   // required
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename)); // provide file size
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    readfile($filename);        // push it out



    echo $output;

    exit;
```

Do we need to restart server after adding any new controller.
please let me know what is the mistake in  this code.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please, for the love of <insert deity of choice her> use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function when you're creating a CSV file, rather than this hodge-podge homebrew of bad advice patched together from a myriad sources on the interweb written by people who didn't know what they were doing

Comment: Hi Mark I have used fputcsv() as suggest by you. still no able to prompt for download after uploading to server. this working fine in my local computer

Comment: Using `fputcsv()` doesn't answer your download question, but it should create a valid csv file without all that excessive and convoluted code that you had

Comment: Points to note about the download: you should only have a single `Content-Type` header

Comment: If you're using a framework of some kind, you may need to do something to prevent it from sending its own headers